# How can I quickly set a Python bytearray to 0

Tags: python

When a Python bytearray is created (with an integer passed to it) it creates a bytearray of that many bytes, and sets them all to zero.

I want to clear the bytearray, and it could be quite large, iterating over it and setting the contents to zero that way is pretty poor.

Is there a better way?

(memoryviews and bytearrays are poorly documented IMO)

Best resources so far (but none of them answer my question)

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#bytearray

Comment: "memoryviews and bytearrays are poorly documented IMO" - that's a ridiculous claim. The first you link to tells you about `translate()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree, I love Python for prototyping, and I'm using wxPython, creating a library to do this for me (while trivial and short) would not be so cross-platform. I've never tried to compile stuff for Windows before (on Linux). This is a prototype, so Python is the right tool.

Comment: @millimoose, but oddly `__init__` isn't mentioned at all on that link. And it can be useful to call it explicitly for `bytearrays`

Comment: @gnibbler Presumably because it's an implementation detail. That is, a different implementation / future version of Python does not need to zero out the underlying array in `__init__()` but in `__new__()`. (For some reason or another.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This answer is wrong. `s = s.translate('\0'*256)` is slower than `s = bytearray(256)`, so there is no point in using `translate` here. @gnibbler provides [a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19671429/190597).

---

Bytearrays have many of the same methods that strings have. You could use the translate method:

```
In [64]: s = bytearray('Hello World')

In [65]: s
Out[65]: bytearray(b'Hello World')

In [66]: import string

In [67]: zero = string.maketrans(buffer(bytearray(range(256))),buffer(bytearray(256)))

In [68]: s.translate(zero)
Out[68]: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

By the way, Dave Beazley has written a very useful [introduction to bytearrays](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html).

---

Or, slightly modifying millimoose's answer:

```
In [72]: s.translate('\0'*256)
Out[72]: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')

In [73]: %timeit s.translate('\0'*256)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 282 ns per loop

In [74]: %timeit s.translate(bytearray(256))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 398 ns per loop
```

Comment: This looks promising actually, is this method slow?

Comment: In CPython, the translate method is written in C, so it is generally much faster than setting the elements using a Python loop.

Comment: Here is the [source code for bytearray.translate](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1787277915e9/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l1443).

Comment: According to the docs for translate "Return a copy of B, where all characters occurring in the optional argument deletechars are removed..." so you'll still need temporary RAM, and you don't get to keep the same reference to `s`

Comment: @gnibbler You're looking at `string.translate()`, not `bytearray.translate()`. `bytearray`s are mutable.

Comment: @millimoose, I used `help(bytearray)`

Comment: @gnibbler Derp. Sorry, my bad, I was misremembering what I was doing in the console. (This also makes my answer wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

Why would you assume reallocating the bytearray is so slow? It's more than 10 times faster than using `translate` or large bytearrays!

I'm deleting the original bytearray so you don't have to worry about temporarily using double the memory

```
# For small bytearray reallocation is a tiny bit faster

$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('Hello World')" "s.translate('\0'*256)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.672 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('Hello World')" "lens=len(s);del s;s=bytearray(lens)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.522 usec per loop


# For large bytearray reallocation is much faster

$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('Hello World'*10000)" "s.translate('\0'*256)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('Hello World'*10000)" "lens=len(s);del s;s=bytearray(lens)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 usec per loop
```

There's an even better way that allow `s` to keep the same reference. You simply need to call the `__init__` method on the instance.

```
>>> s=bytearray(b"hello world")
>>> id(s)
3074325152L
>>> s.__init__(len(s))
>>> s
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> id(s)
3074325152L
```

Testing the timing

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('Hello World'*10000)" "s.__init__(len(s))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.7 usec per loop
```

I ran these gigabyte tests on a different computer with more RAM

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('HelloWorld'*100000000)" "s.__init__(len(s))"
10 loops, best of 3: 454 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "s=bytearray('HelloWorld'*100000000)" "s.translate('\0'*256)"
10 loops, best of 3: 1.43 sec per loop
```

Comment: While this is a ... curious result, it is quite important that pointers remain valid. Still <1mb. What about 1gb?

Comment: @AlecTeal, I added a way to retain the same reference to the bottom of my answer

Comment: @AlecTeal: I think this answer is definitely better than mine. I hope you'll accept it so mine can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few different ways of clearing a bytearray without changing the reference (in case other object refer to it):

1. Using clear():

   ```
   >>> a=bytearray(10)
   >>> a
   bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
   >>> a.clear()
   >>> a
   bytearray(b'')
   ```
2. Using slicing:

   ```
   >>> a=bytearray(10)
   >>> a[0:10] = []
   >>> a
   bytearray(b'')
   >>> a=bytearray(10)
   >>> del a[0:10]
   >>> a
   bytearray(b'')
   ```
3. Using del:

   ```
   >>> a=bytearray(10)
   >>> b=a
   >>> del a[0:10]
   >>> a
   bytearray(b'')
   ```

You can verify that if another variable, say `b`, references `a`, none of the above technique will break this. The following technique of resetting `a`, by creating a new bytearray, will break this:

```
>>> a=bytearray(10)
>>> b=a
>>> b is a
True
>>> a=bytearray(10)
>>> b is a
False
```

However, all the above change the array size to 0. Perhaps you want to simply 0 all the items, keeping the size unchanged, and keeping any references valid:

```
>>> a=bytearray(10)
>>> b=a
>>> b is a
True
>>> a[0:10]=bytearray(10)
>>> b is a
True
```

So you can easily, with this technique, 0 any subsection of the array (in fact, of any mutable container).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is re declare your bytearray

```
b = bytearray(LEN_OF_BYTE_ARRAY)
```

Comment: I don't see re-allocation as a solution. It could be a large bytearray

Comment: @AlecTeal Why do you believe that zeroing an array (albeit in C) is much faster than reallocating the same amount of memory (which would also be done in C)?

Comment: @millimoose SIMD instructions. Also on the re-allocation the bytearray is zeroed (according to Python). So it's malloc+zero-out or just zero-out

Comment: Additionally @millimoose reallocation would make any pointers invalid (in the sense, at least, of not pointing where I want them to). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlecTeal If `translate()` uses SIMD I'll eat a hat. (Whatever autovectorisation the compiler can do notwithstanding.) Whereas zeroing the array out can easily use `memset()` from the standard library, which is probably more optimised than C's string manipulation methods. If you do need pointers / aliases to the array to remain valid then that's a valid concern of course. (Also, if you're interacting with this array from a C extension you're writing, you could probably just use `memset()` there. But I'm making an assumption about that based on you mentioning "pointer".)

Comment: @millimoose I know a lot about GCC, if the compiler can prove vectorising would have no side-effects, it will do it. the memory functions are also assumed by the compiler to be "super-efficient", it will use them for structs over a certain size for example (when copying on the stack in C, for a further example). Anyway provided the author was a const-whore (compliment) and GCC was told the target supported SIMD it would work. I shall investigate this later

Comment: @AlecTeal I believe unutbu linked to the source of that method in his answer.